# What exactly is offset in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I do understand what is grid, basically one whole row will have 12 spaces.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Basically what the code above is just dividing the spaces into 3 section but what I don't understand is, whats the point of setting offset?

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-offset-3"></div>
```

Comment: It just adds space before your column

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Offsets are used for spacing elements in the responsive grid.

The unit is based on the column layout.

You can define an offset this way :
col-[breakpoint]-offset-[number of colums]

In this example, admitting our layout is made of 12 columns :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Means that in the medium range of the grid system, **the element will have a width of 6 colums and there will be 3 blank columns before the element** (and **as a consequence, will have 3 blank colums after**).

The result of this is a div of 6 colums width, centered in the container.

There is a example showing how it renders in the Bootstrap documentation.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

Comment: Awesome answer, now i get it!

Comment: What I don't get is how the above example adds up to 12 columns? In other words, don't you have to be explicit about the 3 columns to the right?

Comment: Yes, you don't have to: 12 columns is the default configuration in Boostrap. If you configure an other layout (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/ see @grid-columns param) the classes will behave accordingly.
The 12 columns responsive grid is the most popular as it is the smallest multiple of 2,3 and 4.

Comment: Is the point of offset so you don't have to add empty "spacer" divs to fill in the gaps?

Comment: Yes. Without offsets, you would probably end up having to add empty divs and set grid column classes on them.

Answer (score 3):

Offset means: Move columns to the right using the `.col-md-offset-*` classes. These classes increase the left margin of a column by * columns.

For example `col-md-offset-3` increases the left margin by 3 for medium devices.